# When is an absolute Galois group first-countable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, galois-theory, profinite-groups, first-countable

Let $K$ be a field, $K^{sep}$ its separable closure, and $G = Gal(K^{sep}/K)$ the absolute Galois group of $K$. What are some algebraic conditions on $K$ that ensure that $G$ is first-countable? This is equivalent to there being a countable nested sequence of finite-index open subgroups that intersect trivially, which in turn is equivalent to $G$ being metrizable.

This occurs if $K$ is countable, but for the moment I cannot think of other general criteria.

Comment: Any first-countable absolute Galois group is metrizable and there are examples of profinite groups which are not metrizable, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896598/separable-profinite-group-which-is-not-metrisable). I don't know if this is helpful.